# Elasticsearch GeoMapping with PHP not working

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have the following mapping in Elasticsearch 2.2

```
  "clinics" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "clinic" : {
        "properties" : {
          "address_1" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer" : "standard"
          },
          "city" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "country" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "location" : {
            "type" : "geo_point"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer" : "standard"
          },
          "state" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "zipcode" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer" : "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

I am using PHP to add to the index with Elastiquent5. my toArray() is:

```
public function toArray()
{
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $object = new \stdClass();
    $object->lat = $array['latitude'];
    $object->lon = $array['longitude'];
    $array['location'] = $object;
    return $array;
}
```

When I try to add the item to the index i get the following error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[Solarman][10.0.2.15:9300][indices:data/write/index[p]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[location] is defined as an object in mapping [clinics] but this name is already used for a field in other types"},"status":400}
```

In json format it yields correctly, in php array it is:

```
array:10 [
  "name" => "Clinic A"
  "address_1" => "123 Main St"
  "city" => "NY"
  "state" => "NY"
  "zipcode" => "11111"
  "country" => "US"
  "id" => 6968
  "location" => {#526
    +"lat": 45.2116373
    +"lon": -72.1891546
  }
]
```

If I manually json_encode this and use the `curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200' -d ''`

it goes through - however the PHP doesnt. Any idea where I went wrong?

**clarification**
My goal is to insert the coordinate that my model data is extracting to map to the location field inside the index since I already designed as a geo_point type as defined by my mapping

I do not want to designate a new field in order to solve this. Secondary note: as I mentioned doing a put with the json will yield successfully however not as a php object out with the php drivers for elastic search which yielded the error when it tried to create the document

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error message, `[location]` is defined as an object in mapping `[clinics]` but this name is already used for a field in `properties`. Changing the variable name like the following might work.

```
public function toArray()
{
    $array = parent::toArray();
    $object = new \stdClass();
    $object->lat = $array['latitude'];
    $object->lon = $array['longitude'];
    $array['location_ob'] = $object;
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: can u help me in this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043254/no-alive-nodes-found-in-your-cluster-elasticsearch

Comment: What I want to do is to make location map to the data. So what your solution propose to a new field which is not what I want. I want the location object insert to the mapping of the field that I have designated since I need it as a geo_point which is what I have designated

Comment: Yes, my solution does propose using a new field. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to work out your requirement.